# דברה תורה בלשון בני אדם

Tags: midrash, rashi

There is a well-known machlokes among Tanaim if דברה תורה בלשון בני אדם. I want to know if there is a final psak on this machlokes, especially according to Rashi. Does Rashi ever say which way to pasken? Or are there examples of Rashi explaining a passuk only according to one opinion? Or does a reliable authority (esp. Mizrachi, Gur Aryeh, etc.) say which way Rashi held?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean pasken, considering this isn't a matter of halacha...

Comment: It affects halacha because whether or not you apply this rule affects how you interpret pesukim which will ultimately affect halacha.

Comment: A search of the term (with spelling variants) in Rashi’s commentary on the Torah doesn’t turn up any results. It does turn up one instance of something similar in Bereshis 32:32, but not quite the way it is typically used in the Talmud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many instances in Shas where this term is brought up. Almost every instance is problematic because the same Tanna seems to hold in a different place the exact opposite. To start,  see Bsva Metzia 31a-b and Tosfos Bava Metzia 31b Dibra Torah. Tosfos there seems to say that it some places the pesukim must be Klashon Bnei Adam and in other places it's not. Not much elaboration.
Tosfos in Menachos 17b Mai Haochel, brings a huge list of places in Shas that are contradictory, and tries to offer the same answer. However, he asks from Bava Metzia 74b and Nedarim 3a where the Gemarah states " according to the one who holds Dibra Torah" that obviously there is a shita that holds that everywhere, and its not variable based on the passuk.
Finally,  Tosfos in Sota 24a has a long list of contradictions, and offers a third answer. He says there is one shita of R' Akiva who says we never say Dibra Torah, there's another shita that says that if you can find something to darshan that's similar to what the passuk is taking about then you can darshan, but if you can only find something to darshan in a different subject then we say Dibra Torah. There's a third shita who says that even if you could darshan the repetition for a different subject you would also say it instead of Dibra Torah, however even this shita agrees that in some cases you say Dibra Torah.
So, in conclusion, it's clear from these Tosfos that nearly all Tannaim at some point agree that we can say Dibra Torah. That is indeed the halacha as we see from the Rambam Hilchos Martnas Aniyim 7:9 where he paskens like the shita that says your not mechuyav to give tzedaka to a rich person who doesn't want to use his own money. This shita is R' Shimon who says Dibrah Torah. However, in many other cases (i.e. giving tochocha 100 times)  we don't say Dibra Torah L'halacha. So it depends on each case and each passuk, and there's no over arching rule for all cases.

Additionally, specifically to Rashi and the Mizrachi, see the Mizrachi in Lech Lecha 12:1 where he points out that even though in some cases we say Dibra Torah, we still say in other cases that we can darshan the extra word even though it may not necessarily be extra because the Torah does sometimes say Dibra Torah. With this he explains Rashi in Parshas Lech Lecha who seems to be darshaning the extra word.